# Get all tables programatically in a DB w.r.t relation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using a relational tables. On a button click i have to retrieve the all the tables in my database in such a way that all the Master tables are coming at the Top.( i.e Generate Scripts from the frontend) and save them onto a text file.

Back Ground purpose: I need to generate script for all the tables in the order and while executing the generated script Foreign key Constraint error will not occur.So I need to get table in the order of relations.

How can I retrieve the table in that way?

Comment: This is really confusing. Why is ASP.NET tagged here? Why is C#? Are you creating SQL scripts so that you can duplicate your database objects? Are you trying to display your database structure on the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use SQL Server Management Studio:

Right click [Your DB] -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Next -> Next -> [Select Tables] Next -> ... all the way to the end,

the wizard should be able to create an intelligent scripts that creates dependent objects first.

EDITED (Oct 18, 2011):

If you generate your scripts from the output of the following query, you should have to worry about foreign key dependencies giving you problems:

```
;with tcte(tid, tname, lvl) 
as
(
select st.object_id, st.name, 0 
from sys.tables st left join sys.foreign_keys sfk on sfk.parent_object_id = st.object_id 
where sfk.name is null

union all

select st.object_id, st.name, 1 
from sys.tables st left join sys.foreign_keys sfk on sfk.parent_object_id = st.object_id 
where sfk.parent_object_id = sfk.referenced_object_id

union all

select st.object_id as tid, st.name, tcte.lvl + 1 
from sys.tables st inner join sys.foreign_keys sfk on sfk.parent_object_id = st.object_id 
inner join tcte on tcte.tid = sfk.referenced_object_id
where tcte.tid <> sfk.parent_object_id
)

select tname, max(lvl) lvl from tcte group by tname order by lvl
```

Comment: Sorry i guess wasnt clear in my question. i need to do this programatically. :-)

Comment: @Manek: I edited my answer to include a query that orders your database tables in such a way that if you scripted the tables in the order they are returned by the query, you wont need to worry about foreign key dependencies causing failures

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.. I tried the solution. But it worked only for a database with LESS number of tables and relations.
But I have a database with 50 more tables and a whole lot of relations.

I included  “option (maxrecursion 0);  code at the end of the query which in turn increases the max recursion.” 
So while executing the query with the Database,it being executed for an considerable time and i am not able to arrive at a result.

Is there anything such that i can extend the time more.

Comment: @Manek: The problem is not the number of tables. My bet would be self-referencing tables. Like Employees(EmpId, ManagerId) where ManagerId references EmpId. I have corrected the script but its not foolproof (I know this :) - I will try make it foolproof).

Comment: @Manek: I make some final edits to the script and am optimistic that it should work in whatever weather.